# Add value in jasper report generate by the sum of 2 variables?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a Jasper Report as below:

```
Product    Quantity   Price       Subtotal
a          2          200         400                
b          $F{qua}  $F{price}     $F{qua} * $F{price}
------------------------------------------------
FOOTER    $V{qua}      -          ???
```

How can I make a total ( sum of all subtotal = ???), I tried something like this:

```
<variable name="foo" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Group1" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{costo}  * $F{cantidad}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
```

But that only gave me last subtotal value instead of sum of all. Any Idea?

I know I can past a new column with the subtotal but is there any way using only Jasper?

Comment: Set the setting in `resetType` to `Report`?

Comment: Check in summary band your variable and resetType to Report

Comment: Its a bir unclear what you like to achieve, "last subtotal value instead of sum of all" , "new column with the subtotal",  anyway tobi6 is right, you need probably just to change the resetType and remember to set correct evaluationTime